# Is there a record of how party strength in the House of Lords has changed over time?

Tags: united-kingdom, house-of-lords

This article: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Members_of_the_House_of_Lords shows how the parties (and non parties) stand right now.

Is there any collection of information about how many members they used to have?

Edit: I'd like the information as a plain ole table if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This website](http://myparliament.info/Historical/Lords) shows the House of Lords membership by party and genders of the Members over the last 30 years.

> View the makeup of the House of Lords showing the party and genders of the Members at any specified date over the last 30 years.